# How to call a superclass method recursivly

Tags: scala, recursion, super

In Scala, recursively calling a method of a super class doesn't seem to go through the whole class hierarchy.

Assuming the following simple class tree:

```
class A {
def f: Int = 1
def g: Int = 0
}

class B extends A {
override def f: Int = g + super.f
override def g: Int = 10
}

class C extends B{
override def g: Int = 20
}

class D extends C{
override def g: Int = 30
}

val d = new D
printf("f.d = " + d.f)
```

I expected the result to be 61 but got 31 instead, B::f is obviously only called once (Snippet edited for clarification).
Of course, it works the way I want, if I redefine `f()` in each subclass, but that seems rather superfluous and gets really nasty, if the class tree gets bigger.

So is there some better way of achieving the desired result?

Comment: `D.f` is basically a call to `C.f`, which is a call to `B.f`, which is `1 + A.f`. 1 + 1 = 2. You're not adding anything to the super calls in `D` and `C`.

Comment: What's the initial problem you want to solve with this approach?

Comment: I came up with this problem while working on a DSL that maintains its own type inheritance tree. It would have been nice, if I could use the Scala class tree to mirror these dependencies.

Comment: The actual method I use  is somewhat more complex than just adding 1. It involves calling other methods that are overridden differently for each subclass.